# Natural interpolation in R

Tags: r, interpolation, spline, linear-interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate data by using the *spline* function (*stats* R package).

Specifically, I have a dataset like the following one:

```
DATE    Y
01/01/2020  
02/01/2020  0.705547512
04/01/2020  0.760723591
06/01/2020  0.014017642
07/01/2020  
09/01/2020  0.579518616
10/01/2020  
12/01/2020  0.7747401
15/01/2020  0.289562464
19/01/2020
```

I would like to learn how to interpolate missing data on the base of the other values (e.g. Y variable values for the January 1st, January 7th,...).
The aim is to populate such missing data; in order to do that, browsing on the internet, I found the *spline* R function that should do this task.

Can someone help me to compute the interpolated data?
Thanks in advance.

So, I tried to implement the following R code in order to interpolate missing data.

```
SPLINE<- spline(x=df[2],
       y=df[1],
       method = "natural")$y
```

The outcome is a numeric vector with 3 record; all of them are equal to 10.
I don't understand the ratio behind this kind of interpolation since I expected a vector with 10 record and all observations equal to the original Y variable except for the record corresponding the 2020-01-07, 2020-01-10 and 2020-01-19 that were missing and the spline function populates with the selected method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what your problem is because your data is not reproducible. Are those *really* empty cells in your data frame? A numeric column can't have empty cells - they would have to be NA values. If they look empty when you print the data frame, then it is a character column and must be converted to numeric, or else `spline` won't work. Also, are those *real* date objects, or are they just character strings that represent dates? Again, if they are character strings, `spline` won't work.

Let's take your example data as given:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "
DATE    Y
01/01/2020  ''
02/01/2020  0.705547512
04/01/2020  0.760723591
06/01/2020  0.014017642
07/01/2020  ''
09/01/2020  0.579518616
10/01/2020  ''
12/01/2020  0.7747401
15/01/2020  0.289562464
19/01/2020  ''
", header = TRUE)
```

Now we convert to the correct formats:

```r
df$DATE <- as.Date(df$DATE, format = '%d/%m/%Y')
df$Y    <- as.numeric(df$Y)
```

Following which, `spline` works just fine. Let's use it to generate a smooth line consisting of 100 points:

```r
SPLINE  <- spline(x = df$DATE, y = df$Y, n = 100, method = 'natural')

plot(df$DATE, df$Y, ylim = c(-0.1, 1))
lines(SPLINE$x, SPLINE$y)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer Allan. You were really helpful!